# Display of @Environment(\.description) behaves inconsistently

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, environment-variables

The following code was written to display a single string (6000 chars) of environment values:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.description) var description
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("@Environment Values").font(.title)
            
            ScrollView {
                Text("\(description)").font(.caption)
            }.padding()
        }
    }
}
```

The result is inconsistent on both simulator and iPhone. When run, sometimes the information is displayed as desired on the left but often no values are displayed as shown on the right:
[image]

Other things tried didn't resolve the problem. Placing the environment variable in a viewmodel gives the message "Accessing Environment's value outside of being installed on a View. This will always read the default value and will not update."

Splitting the string into two strings gives the same inconsistent results.

Is this a thread issue?
Outside of listing every environment key and value, can anything be done to display the @Environment(.description) consistently?

Comment: How very strange! I'm seeing the same thing, about 50% of the time. Tried splitting on `","`, refreshing the view after a delay, reloading on change of `description`, displaying on a subview after a delay… nothing fixed it.

Comment: @AshleyMills Thank-you for your feedback and effort. I'm glad to know it wasn't my mac setup. I've filed a report with Apple.

Comment: The problem appears to have been fixed. The code above appears to work 100% of the time now.